# Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable even if the comparable is implemented

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparable

I want to sort an arraylist which contains "Counter" objects with Collections.sort() method. I have implemented the comparable interface in the Counter class. Still i get a class cast exception. I have posted the code below.

```
public class Counter implements Comparable<Counter>, java.io.Serializable {

    private String description;

    public Counter() {
    }

    public Counter(String description) {

        this.description = description;

    }

    public int compareTo(Counter other) {
        return description.compareTo(other.description);
    }
}
```

The below method is where i call the sort method.

```
    protected List < Counter > prepareCounters(final Integer authorityID) throws ServiceException {
    if (authorityID == null) {
        return new ArrayList < Counter >();
    }

    List < Counter > countersInRegistry = new ArrayList < Counter >(counterRegistry.getAllCounters());
    List < Counter > countersFromService =
            new ArrayList < Counter >(counterService.searchCounters(authorityID, null, null));
    countersFromService.removeAll(countersInRegistry);
    Collections.sort(countersFromService);
    return countersFromService;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that throws the exception.

Comment: And the actual exception, which should reference the file name, class name, and line number where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Post the code where you are performing sort operation.

Comment: You're most likely trying to sort a list that has also other, incompatible objects. The generic `compareTo()` method has an implicit cast in it, and that will fail if the other object is not a `Counter`.

Answer (score 3):

Is working for me, (OpenJDK7)>

// Main ----------------------------------------------------

```
package stackover_basic;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class StackOver_basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Counter> asList = Arrays.asList(new Counter("xx"), new Counter("aa"), new Counter("zz"));
        System.out.println("before" + asList);
        Collections.sort(asList);        
        System.out.println("after" + asList);
   }
}
```

// Counter -------------------------------------------------

```
public class Counter implements Comparable<Counter>, java.io.Serializable {

    private String description;

    public Counter() {
    }

    public Counter(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Counter other) {
        return description.compareTo(other.description);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Counter{" + "description=" + description + '}';
    }
}
```

Output>

```
run:
before[Counter{description=xx}, Counter{description=aa}, Counter{description=zz}]
after[Counter{description=aa}, Counter{description=xx}, Counter{description=zz}]
```

EDIT: Is highly possible that the classCastExc comes from your definition of compareTo. The reason: Your are adding a wrong object to the collection, i.e the return types of the methods  `counterService.searchCounters` and `counterRegistry.getAllCounters` are not generic in Counter class.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing particularly wrong with the code the OP has posted so far.  The problem is almost certainly with the calling code, which we haven't seen yet.  This answer doesn't really add much to the discussion.

Comment: According to the low level of info, is completely valid. He cant sort, I'm showing him how to do it.

Comment: I edited the question including the calling method of Collections.sort() .

Comment: @Pathfinder92 read the edit;